# IIS Rewrite rules for PHP Zend application migrated from Apache

Tags: php, iis, zend-framework, url-rewriting

Versions:
PHP 5.5
Zend v 2.5
IIS V 10

Hi, I have migrated an apache website to IIS with a simple copy and paste and setup rewrite rules from the HTAccess file.  The site all works fine accept when a modal with a button that has <a href="#" is clicked.  The button should simply close the modal but instead it takes you back to the home page.  I imagine the rewrites are wrong but I have searched everywhere and nothing seems to change the behaviour.

Rewrite Rules:

```
 <rule name="Imported Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">  
                      <match url="^.*$" />  
                      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">  
                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />

                          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />  
                      </conditions>  
                      <action type="None" />  
                  </rule>  
                  <rule name="Imported Rule 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">  
                      <match url="^.*$" />  
                      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />  
                  </rule>
```

I tried many different rules on the internet but nothing changed.  I tried ignoring # in the rules which did nothing but I am unsure if my rule was correct.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. your problem seems to be with the button, how did you define your button? or you can just tell me which url you want to rewrite.

Comment: Hi, this button should do nothing but close the modal.  When clicked however it redirects back to index.php, I believe the rewrite rules cause this and need to prevent this action.  Button HTML:  `<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all" role="button">Ok</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to rewrite to `index.php` when click the `<a>` tag, you can try to use outboundrule in iis. I have a test.html page with only  tag in it, when I click on it, it will add a "#" end of the url, so I use the outbound rule to rewrite it to `index.php`.

```
<rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
        <rule name="CustomRedirect">
           <match filterByTags="None" pattern="#" />
           <action type="Rewrite" value="index.php" />
        </rule>
   </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

This is test result:

[image]